# Emulate broken NestJS endpoints without restart the entire API project

Tags: api, nestjs

I have an Angular and NestJS project. I would need to emulate a broken API endpoint without stop restart the entire NestJS project, like any actuator in Spring framework, but in a separated maintenance app that allow me to test the Angular access to remote broken API endpoints.

I tried with a NodeJS app that changes the `/etc/hosts` files in realtime.

Comment: what about just overwritting the HTTP response sent using browser extensions like https://tweak-extension.com/?

Comment: For direct API endpoint between Angular and NestJS works fine, but when the NestJS is a facade endpoint between Angular and other endpoint, the latest one is not blocked because is managed through the NestJS application.

Comment: oh I got it now

Comment: Found that I can block by IP using pf in mac, but for custom paths doesn't work. In example if I need to block `https://ip:port` it works but it blocks all paths for the API, If i only need to block `https://ip:port/custom-path` it doesn't allow me to block